# Jasmine debugging backtrace using jasmine-headless-webkit on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

Can I get somehow a deeper Error backtrace when I run

> jasmine-headless-webkit
>      Running Jasmine specs...
>      ..F
>      FAIL: 3 tests, 1 failure, 0.019 secs.
>
> (/Users/User/Development/project/spec/javascripts/modal_spec.coffee:14)
>     TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

I want to know where exactly in the JS the error occurs. A nice backtrace would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115916/better-failure-report-in-jasmine-headless-webkit), you can use

```
jasmine-headless-webkit --runner-out ~/Desktop/jasmine-out.html
```

to generate a nice report with nice backtrace. Just open the generated html in your favorite browser