# Better failure report in Jasmine headless webkit

Tags: jasmine, error-reporting, headless

I've got a simple `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object` failure when running a test in  Jasmine headless webkit. But there is no hint in which file or line the error occurs. Is there  a way to get a clearer failure message?

Comment: Do you see any error at all in the browser? Also do you happen to use require.js? I remember seeing the same in the past but can't remember how I resolved it...

Comment: The problem is not the error itself but the lossy hint where the error happens. Running the test in the browser will give you the line number anyway, but the question is about a headless webkit.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the --runner-out  flag to save the HTML from the test.  Open this in a browser and you will see the full stacktrace.

```
jasmine-headless-webkit --runner-out ~/Desktop/jasmine-out.html
```

Answer (score -3):

Try debug in Firebug (Firefox) or Google Chrome. Just press F12 and go to scripts pane. I suggest firebug. If that not help you can post your code here or, better, at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its not about finding a bug in a normal browser but in a headless webkit turing running a jasmin test, so there is no firebug  or developer tools.

Comment: Ok, in this case maybe you should post your issue on github: https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit/issues