# Is there a way to use debug on Jasmine Headless webkit?

Tags: jasmine

Is there a way to use debug on Jasmine Headless webkit?

Maybe something like

```
describe "Some Test", ->
  it "should break on debugger", ->
    console.log("before debugger")
    debugger
    console.log("after debugger")
```

and have similar effect as debugger on Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12203381/1920122), you can use the runner-out flag to generate a nice report with a backtrace for any failures. It's not interactive like debugger, but it is quite nice.

`jasmine-headless-webkit --runner-out tmp/jhw-out.html`

**Note:** you can also set this flag in the .jasmine-headless-webkit file of your project or home directory, particularly useful if you're using Guard.